# Maven exec incorrectly adds single quotes to bash commands

Tags: bash, maven

Edit: It was by my mistake that Maven behaved this way. Case closed.

---

I want to run a series of commands in bash from my POM file. One of the commands takes a list of file as its parameter. What I want is to run it like this:

```
protoc --java_out=./outdir --proto_path="somepath" somepath/file1 somepath/file2
```

However, when I invoke this from inside the maven exec, this is actually run:

```
protoc --java_out=./outdir --proto_path=somepath 'somepath/file1 somepath/file2'
```

And bash then thinks that there is only one file which, obviously, does not exist.

I assume that Maven detects if there is a space in an argument and then tries to help by putting in the single quotes, but in this case I don't want that to happen.

Below is the exec plugin configuration. All the variables are assigned when the pom is executed and it does work with only a single file as an argument. This is an archetype for similar builds and I want to be able to generate concrete poms with different lists of files.

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
    <id>compile-sources</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <executable>bash</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-c</argument>
            <argument>
                set -x -E -e
                export PATH="${basedir}/${unpackPath}/bin/:${PATH}"
                export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="${basedir}/${unpackPath}/lib/:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}"

                chmod u+x "${unpackPath}/bin/"*
                rm -rf "${compiledSrcPath}"
                mkdir -p "${compiledSrcPath}"

                protoc \
                --java_out=./"${compiledSrcPath}" \
                --proto_path="${protoPath}" \
                ${protoFiles}
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
```

Edit: it seems the problem already arises when the project is generated from the archetype. The resulting pom.xml contains `"file1 file2"` in place of the original `${protoFiles}`.

Answer (score 2):

I got mixed up in my own versions of the archetype and was mistakenly using one which had the `"${protoFiles}"` enclosed in quotes.

If the variable is not enclosed in quotes, Maven will not add any and it will work as expected.

Comment: This helped me adding `geckodriver` in `argument` tag  of `exec-maven-plugin` to register a node to the hub like this `-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/geckodriver` . Previously , I was adding the path in quotes , which did not work